# Not able to include ntifs.h in win32 project

Tags: c, winapi, kernel

I tried to use the function called `NTCreateFile`. When I compiled it gave me an error saying 
"_NTCreateFile identifier not found". I inlcuded the header `winternl.h`. So next I tried to use `ZwCreatFile`, as per MSDN I included `ntifs.h`, but I am not able to include that header. It says "not able to open/find the directory". I am using V@2008. What is the problem? Am I missing anything?

**EDIT1:**

```
typedef NTSTATUS (*fp_CreatFile)(
    OUT PHANDLE FileHandle,
    IN ACCESS_MASK DesiredAccess,
    IN POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjectAttributes,
    OUT PIO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatusBlock,
    IN PLARGE_INTEGER AllocationSize OPTIONAL,
    IN ULONG FileAttributes,
    IN ULONG ShareAccess,
    IN ULONG CreateDisposition,
    IN ULONG CreateOptions,
    IN PVOID EaBuffer OPTIONAL,
    IN ULONG EaLength
    );
OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES myAttributes;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    fp_CreatFile myFunction;
    HMODULE module = LoadLibrary(L"ntdll.dll");
    if(NULL != module)
    {
        myFunction = (fp_CreatFile)GetProcAddress(module,"NtCreateFile");
    }

    UNICODE_STRING string;
    IO_STATUS_BLOCK fileStatus;
    string.Length = 56;
    string.Buffer = L"C:\\user\\kiddo\\Desktop\\7zFM.exe";
    string.MaximumLength = 56;

    HANDLE fileHandle;
    myAttributes.ObjectName = &string;
    myAttributes.Length = sizeof(OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES);
    long mystatus = myFunction(&fileHandle,FILE_GENERIC_READ,&myAttributes ,&fileStatus,NULL,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,FILE_SHARE_READ,
        NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

When it tries to call that it gives the following error in a Message box.
**ERROR:**
Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call.  This is usually a result of calling a function declared with one calling convention with a function pointer declared with a different calling convention.

Comment: You should post the compiler output messages verbatim (a copy & paste would be simpler and more accurate that a *description*); it is important to know whether or not this is a linker or compiler error (the message would tell us that).  Obviously the file not found is a pro-processor error, but what about *before* your attempt to fix the original problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you read the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb432380%28VS.85%29.aspx), the first paragraph says:

> Note  Before using this function,
>   please read [Calling Internal APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb432200%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Which says that: (I highlighted the important parts)

> The Winternl.h header file exposes
>   prototypes of internal Windows APIs.
>   There is no associated import library,
>   **so developers must use run-time
>   dynamic linking to call the functions**
>   described in this header file.
>
> The functions and structures in
>   Winternl.h are internal to the
>   operating system and subject to change
>   from one release of Windows to the
>   next, and possibly even between
>   service packs for each release. To
>   maintain the compatibility of your
>   application, you should use the
>   equivalent public functions instead.
>   Further information is available in
>   the header file, Winternl.h, and the
>   documentation for each function.
>
> If you do use these functions, **you can
>   access them through run-time dynamic
>   linking using [LoadLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684175%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and
>   [GetProcAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683212%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)**. This gives your code
>   an opportunity to respond gracefully
>   if the function has been changed or
>   removed from the operating system.
>   Signature changes, however, may not be
>   detectable.

So you'll have to load the functions you want to use from `NtDll.dll` before being able to use them.

Here is a **non-tested** example code sample:

```
typedef NTSTATUS (__stdcall *NtCreateFile)(
    OUT PHANDLE FileHandle,
    IN ACCESS_MASK DesiredAccess,
    IN POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjectAttributes,
    OUT PIO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatusBlock,
    IN PLARGE_INTEGER AllocationSize OPTIONAL,
    IN ULONG FileAttributes,
    IN ULONG ShareAccess,
    IN ULONG CreateDisposition,
    IN ULONG CreateOptions,
    IN PVOID EaBuffer OPTIONAL,
    IN ULONG EaLength
    );

NtCreateFile _NtCreateFile = (NtCreateFile)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("ntdll.dll"),"NtCreateFile");

// You can now use the function
_NtCreateFile(/* params */);

// Don't forget the release the resources
```

Comment: thank you for ur response ereOn,I did like what you suggested but there is again an RunTime error..please check my edit further

Comment: @kiddo: Your last error is pretty clear: you try to call a method using another "calling convention" than the one it was compiled for. What if you try one of those in front of your function declaration: `__cdecl`, `__stdcall` (**probably this one**) or  `__fastcall` ? I edited my answer to add the interesting part.

Comment: it worked,but it didnt receive any filehandle..please assist me if u have knowledge about the function NtCreateFile

Comment: @kiddo I never used this function. All I can do is somehow "decipher" the documentation for you and give you general advices. If you really are stuck, I suggest your start a new basic sample project to test this. Once you get it to work, you will be able to compare it with your actual code and find out what is wrong with it.

Comment: hey,ereOn..why dont you give me your e-mail id..we will get in touch...
if you are interested

Answer (score 2):

Several possibilities:

- You say the error message is "_NTCreateFile identifier not found".  The name of the API is `NtCreateFile()` (note the lowercase 't'). It's possible that you're simply using the wrong name.
- `ntifs.h` and related link libraries are included in the Windows Driver Kit (WDK), which can be downloaded from here: http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/wdk/wdkpkg.mspx. You should be able to use the WDK to do what you want a bit more directly than using dynamic linking.  but then you generally have to buy into a whole new build system or figure out how to integrate the headers and libraries into your current build.
- You can use the [dynamic linking technique outlined by ereOn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964941/not-able-to-include-ntifs-h-in-win32-project/2964995#2964995).

Answer (score 1):

ZwCreateFile is part of the Windows Driver Kit, not the Windows SDK.  You would need to install the driver kit. Some macros and types used by NTCreateFile also require WDK headers.  That is clearly stated in the documentation on MSDN.

Answer (score 1):

As clearly indicated by the error message, you got the calling convention wrong, you dropped NTAPI.  It should be:

```
typedef NTSTATUS (__stdcall * fp_CreatFile)(
  // etc..
);
```

Properly initializing myAttributes would normally be important.  I don't see you do anything that would warrant calling the undocumented native API function.  Stick with CreateFile() as long as you can.

Comment: yup,it worked..but it didnt do anything..do have any idea about this function..NtcreatFile

Comment: The native Windows API is undocumented, I'm not supposed to know anything about it.  Surely it did *something*, what's the function return value?

Comment: its a garbage value..some large negative value

Comment: NTSTATUS codes are large values, not garbage.  They are listed in the ntstatus.h SDK header file.